# Print message above PHP contact form

Tags: php, html

Hey all, I have a basic HTML contact form that goes to a .php file after the submit button is clicked. At the moment, if there are no errors when a user presses submit, it brings them to a separate page saying "Thank you for contacting us...". Would it be possible to print that message above the contact form when they click submit? I would really like them to just stay on the current page instead of getting redirected.

Here's the HTML form:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="scripts/contactform.php">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name"><b>Name *</b></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email"><b>Email Address *</b></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone"><b>Telephone</b></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="message">Message: *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="message" maxlength="1000" cols="40" rows="8"></textarea>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="height:35px; width:90px;">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here is the contactform.php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "email@domain.com";
    $email_subject = "Contact Form";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
  if(!eregi($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "^[a-z .'-]+$";
  if(!eregi($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!eregi($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- Success HTML -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you as soon as possible.

<?
}
?>
```

Any ideas on what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use AJAX.  Here is an example of what you want to do:

http://www.bitrepository.com/a-simple-ajax-contact-form-with-php-validation.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$flag = 0;
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
$flag=1;
   // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "email@domain.com";
    $email_subject = "Contact Form";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
  if(!eregi($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "^[a-z .'-]+$";
  if(!eregi($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!eregi($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- Success HTML -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you as soon as possible.

<?
}
?>

<?php
if($flag==0)
{
?>
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="scripts/contactform.php">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name"><b>Name *</b></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email"><b>Email Address *</b></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone"><b>Telephone</b></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="message">Message: *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="message" maxlength="1000" cols="40" rows="8"></textarea>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="height:35px; width:90px;">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to have your contact form as a PHP file so that it can conditionally display the error message.

You can do that in one of two ways:

1. Have the contactform.php file redirect back to the HTML form if an error occurs. In this case, you'll have to save the error message to a session variable.
2. Include all the form processing at the top of the HTML form, and have the form's action point to itself.

Then, right above the form, just include something like

```
<?php if (!empty($error_message)): ?>
    <p class="error"><?php echo $error_message; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```